Cant get proper obj copies from alembic frames
I am currently working on vertex animation texture generation inside blender and I got pretty far, I specifically was working on remeshing water simulations to always use constant amount of vertices/polygons.
But now I wanted to debug it with a simple Icosphere rolling down from a slope,
The problem is Blender refuses to make correct copies and get the correct vertex position data even tho it fully works for imported alembic files of water drops but not a simple rigid body simulation?
They both are mesh cash animated objects inside blender and the script expects them to be
relevant function from my script:
https://pastebin.com/cc96nB5j

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, add code snippets, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in text form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
